# A test of mental acuity; Identify me

Tags: riddle, cipher, word, limerick

> When I spike, you will get quite enthused,
>   For great strength, I am often abused,
>   I am quintessentially male...
>   The next line might derail:
>   With Hashish amiga, my name's all confused.

Who or what am I?

Note that the fourth line is simply referring to the fact that the fifth line is the hardest, and the key to the whole puzzle.

<s>Hint: I've left off a tag that is appropriate to this question, intentionally.</s> - updated now that the puzzle has been available for a few more days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Geobits for help on the last line!

> Testosterone

When I spike, you will get quite enthused,

> Testosterone is often related to libido, and when that spikes.... Well, you know.

For great strength, I am often abused,

> Testosterone is often used as a steroid to help bodybuilders.

I am quintessentially male...

> Testosterone and male are almost synonyms in today's society.

The next line might derail:
 With Hashish amiga, my name's all confused.

> Hashishamiga is a substitute-cipher for testosterone.
> $H->T$, $A->E$, $S$ is the same, $I->O$, $M->R$, and $G->N$
>  Each vowel goes to the "next." Not sure how the others were generated though.

And the missing tag should be

> "Cryptograms", though "rhyme" would fit as well.

Comment: "hashishamiga" is a simple substitution for "testosterone", as in h->t, etc. I can't figure out why certain letters were chosen to substitute, but I assume it was just to make it pronounceable and rhythmic.

Comment: @Geobits, to me that makes no sense xD

Comment: Well done. That is indeed the solution, and Geobits correctly identified how the last line fits in. It was chosen to fit without being an obvious cipher (I didn't intend the possible misinterpretation of "hashish" as a drug, as shettysahab thought). I hoped that "my name is all confused" would hint at some sort of shuffling - without a nice anagram, the next choice would be "confusing" the letters themselves, hence the cipher. I'd say "cipher" is the missing tag, rather than "cryptogram", but they're very similar. I'll add the tag soon.

Comment: Note that testosterone is the only relatively-common word that "hashishamiga" becomes by substitution, as can be confirmed by resources like this: http://www.hanginghyena.com/solvers/cryptogram-helper ... oh, and while "rhyme" could apply to the question, there's really no reason to leave it off. Cipher/cryptogram would have been a huge hint towards "hashishamiga" being a cryptogram, and I didn't want to give that away too quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

> steroids

When I spike, you will get quite enthused,

> some kind of drug

For great strength, I am often abused,

> steroids give more strength

I am quintessentially male...

> males often use this drug.

The next line might derail:

> your life/career might derail if you get caught using it (also, some scientific article about derailing T cells? )

With Hashish amiga, my name's all confused.

> yes I am confused by this

Comment: The next line might derail is just saying that the line after it is the hardest part - I needed a rhyme to complete the limerick. You are somewhat on the right track, though.

Comment: @GlenO with amiga do you mean the computer line? Also i would have thought: my name's all confused would mean an anagram, but hashish has not anagram.. (none that i can come up with) i thought that might be the tag missing

Comment: You're starting to think a little more in the direction necessary to solve it, but the missing tag isn't "anagram". And no, "amiga" isn't a reference to computers.

Comment: @GlenO is amiga like amigo? like hey amigo/dude?

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> Cannabis/Marijuana

When I spike, you will get quite enthused,

> It is a drug

With Hashish amiga, my name's all confused.

> It is known by many names

A test of mental acuity

> long-term cannabis users show morphological brain alterations.

Comment: Hashish as a reference to marijuana is a red herring ("Hashish" is relevant to the answer, but not in that way).